# Can't get response from json

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit2

I'm trying to get the response from json but I get a nullpointer error

Here is my retrofit interface

```
public interface RequestGeo {

@Headers("user-key: mykey")
@GET("geocode?lat=49.195061&lon=16.606836")
Call<JSONResponse> getJSON();
}
```

On my MainActivity i got this code

```
private void loadJSON() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://developers.zomato.com/api/v2.1/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    RequestGeo request = retrofit.create(RequestGeo.class);
    Call<JSONResponse> call = request.getJSON();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JSONResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<JSONResponse> call, Response<JSONResponse> response) {

            JSONResponse jsonResponse = response.body();
            geoCodeData = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getGeocode()));
            adapter = new RestaurantListAdapter(geoCodeData);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<JSONResponse> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("Error", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

The nullpointerexception error is here

```
geoCodeData = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(jsonResponse.getGeocode()));
```

Here is my jsonResponse.java file

```
public class JSONResponse {

    private Geocode[] geocode;

    public Geocode[] getGeocode(){
        return geocode;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Geocode.java class where I write the variables exactly as the json objects I want to get (there are more but i don't want them).

```
@Entity
public class Geocode {


@NonNull
@PrimaryKey private String title;
private String latitude;
private String longitude;
private String city_name;


public Geocode(String title, String latitude, String longitude, String city_name) {
    this.title = title;
    this.latitude = latitude;
    this.longitude = longitude;
    this.city_name = city_name;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLatitude() {
    return latitude;
}

public void setLatitude(String latitude) {
    this.latitude = latitude;
}

public String getLongitude() {
    return longitude;
}

public void setLongitude(String longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

public String getCity_name() {
    return city_name;
}

public void setCity_name(String city_name) {
    this.city_name = city_name;
}
}
```

Comment: i think your response is null, please check your response with postman.

Comment: @Radesh on postman i got the url you see and i use the "user-key"as a header and it works

Comment: no annotations on the JSONResponse class? also, please post Geocode class code. Thanks

Comment: @Lino sorry i'm new programmer.What should i put?

Comment: It depends on how the json fields are named. In theory annotations might be skipped if your json is something like this: `{ 
 "geocode":[
    {
    "title":"entry title",
    "latitude":"32.1",
    "longitude":"34.2",
    "city_name": "Detroit"
   }
 ]
}`

Comment: @AlexKolydas make sense?

Comment: @Lino i think yeah.Now i'm trying to do it with volley maybe it is easier